# google analytics content groupings error

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-datalayer, data-layer

I have configurated some content groupings through the datalayer (extracted wordpress pagecategory as a variable, and prepared the basic analytics code to tell the content group based on the variable extracted). Everything should be working fine, when I test with the tag manager debugger, you can see the content group extracted perfectly.

The thing is, when you get inside the analytics, you see that sometimes that same page goes to its supposed content group, and sometimes goes to "Not set" group. I implemented the content groups on 9th of august, both have all their data from that date onwards ( so I dont think it has to do with historical data). This seems to be happening with more than 80% of the total traffic. Any idea what I could be doing to debug this? Everytime I get inside the tag manager debugger, the content group call is showed perfectly fine

I use tag manager plugin on wordpress to configurate the datalayer.
https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/duracelltomi-google-tag-manager/
Universal analytics tag is implemented.  Wordpress is version 4.9.8 .

[Here you can see the contentgroup call being fired on data layer and analytics, with the tag manager debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgHge.png)

[Here you can see overall data of content groupings inside analytics ( They do seem to be firing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6Rox.png)

[Here you can see that the page does track effectively inside its content group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgy52.png)

[But also tracks that same page inside " not set" content group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKIKD.png)

Its really weird, eveyry time I use debugger on the page, the content group call is donde fine, with no problems. But inside the analytics data that same page  is being located to two different content groupings, the true one, and " not set".

How can I debug this? What could  be wrong?

here are the configuration pics
    https://drive.google.com/open?id=10ICT2PTwdBgc1uTyom37IU7CfKKMt9a4

I cant share more than 8, so I had to solve with a google drive share.

Here on the other hand is the content group report update
[content group report update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMgHK.png)

Comment: Can you update the content group report screenshots and also share your content group config screen shot.

Comment: done, thank you for your interest, you are the only one who has talked to me about this problem.

Comment: he can you share the URL please, I think I am close as to why this is happening. Your configuration seems to be right though. is it eventplanningblueprint dot com?

Comment: That is correct, lets see. The domain is eventplanningblueprint.com and the url of the blog post that gives me the most trouble is https://eventplanningblueprint.com/your-10-steps-to-becoming-an-event-planner/

Comment: The three tags make perfect sense, the client had a global tag implemented which I thought was able to remove by deactivating a code specfied on the wordpress theme integrations, just after that I activated the universal analytics through google tag manager. So this means, there are three google analytics codes right now tracking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ASSUMPTION - the URL is editing thr URL for privacy reasons**. I will edit this out after OP comments

The configurations are all correct I have gone through it multiple times to check. 
The problem is you are sending 3 pageviews at the moment where there should be only 1 on one GA ID.

If you go into the source code, you will find that you have gtag.js firing a pageview, analytics.js firing a pageview and then there is Google Tag Manager firing a pageview.

Now to the meat of the problem - The content grouping that you see is because of the Google Tag Manager configuration, but as you have enabled content grouping, the pageviews from gtag.js and analytics.js do not send any content grouping information hence the (not set). And this also explains why one page would be categorised into a content group as well (not set).

PS - Posting this as the solution as I have already invested enough time trying to debug it :)

Comment: thank you, its a hypothesis, you have really helped me

Comment: Then there is this problem, why if that is the case, when I check real time reports while I´m visiting the page, would only show me one user visit? Would it not, in that case, have to show more than one? Either two or three visits? Could you at least give me your opinion in this aspect? Dont need to waste more time than just giving your opinion about this

Comment: Ha, that is because real time reports look at active users, and all of them consider as you as single user, try to look at pageview tab in Real time, you will get the 3 pageviews. There is a difference between Real Time user and pageviews

Comment: you were right, my god you are a pro man. I oficcially admire you. The guy that implemented the code placed it three times aparrently, the only code of the three I removed was the one he implemented through a plugin. Where and how he implemented the other two is a mistery, I´m not able to find it. I´l have to talk with the previous analist / developer to debug this

Comment: Awesome, glad to help you out